# How to make --full the default for `systemctl status`?

Tags: systemd

I have `SYSTEMD_PAGER` set to cat, to avoid having long lines truncated. However, when I type `systemctl status <service>`, instead of truncating long lines at the end, it now inserts an ellipsis and *still* does not show the full line!

The manpage says passing `-l` or `--full` will fix this — and it does — but how can I make this (correct) behaviour the default?

There is no mention of an environment variable I can set to enable this, and setting a shell alias isn't possible, as you cannot have spaces in alias names like `alias 'systemd status'='systemd status -l'`.

I don't want to have an alias with a different name — I just want to make `-l` the default for `systemd status`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-l` doesn't have to come after the `status` so you could simply use

```
alias systemctl='systemctl -l'
```

This does of course make this the default setting for all the other subcommands as well.

Answer (score 3):

When the functionality of aliases is not sufficient, the next step up is using a shell function. Like this, for example:

```
systemctl() {
    if [ "$1" = "status" ]
    then
        /bin/systemctl -l "$@"
    else
        /bin/systemctl "$@"
    fi
}
```